# Custom CoreData-Migration doesn't use default value

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

For my next version I changed the *CoreData-Model* in a big way, so I decided to use a custom migration.

I got the migration it self to work fine, but when I tried to use the mapping model instead of the migration policy for a class, *the migration crashed by saying a (bool/NSNumber) value, that was optional before and isn't now, but has a defined default value, is nil.*

The custom migration policy did work, because I checked, if the old value did exist:

```
if let attribute = sInstance.value(forKey: "attribute") as? NSNumber
{
     dInstance.attribute = attribute
}
else
{
     dInstance.attribute = NSNumber(value: false)
}
```

But if I use the mapping model like this:

```
 attribute = $source.attribute
```

*it crashes.*

Any suggestions what to do?

**EDIT:**

This the error:

```
UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"attribute is a required value.\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<NSManagedObject: 0x191906f0> (entity: Entity; id: 0x17da96a0 <x-coredata://18E7FEF2-9E09-4EF4-98AA-EC641305E39F/Entity/p2> ; data: <fault>), NSValidationErrorKey=attribute, NSLocalizedDescription=attribute is a required value.}",
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"attribute is a required value.\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<NSManagedObject: 0x17f00710> (entity: Entity; id: 0x191898f0 <x-coredata://18E7FEF2-9E09-4EF4-98AA-EC641305E39F/Entity/p1> ; data: <fault>), NSValidationErrorKey=attribute, NSLocalizedDescription=attribute is a required value.}"
)}
```